# How to find number of unique sources for each destination using panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Here is my data :

[image]

I want to have a sliced data frames of the destinations that have more than 20 unique sources. How can I frame it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater:

```
df = df[df.groupby('Destination')['Source'].transform('nunique').gt(20)]
```

Comment: @Trusha_Patel - Because need repeat aggregate values by `nunique` per column, it means get Series with same size like `df`, so possible filtering